# Django - Class Based View - Restrict Access to Views based on User or Group Permissions - UserPassesTestMixin

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, python-3.6

My project is running Django 3.05 and was set up with [Django cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django),
and it uses the custom user model created by the cookiecutter framework.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.User"
```

I have a set of Class Based Views where I want to restrict access
based on group or user permissions.

I do not want to use the PermissionRequiredMixin and redirect to a 403 page. Instead, if a user does not have correct permissions I would simply like to redirect to the referring page, and display a "permission denied" banner message at the top (see screen shot below).

The problem is that these permissions are not working as expected when implemented my Views.

I am able to use either the admin panel or the django shell to assign permissions.

For example here is the permissions as they show up in the shell:

```
In [7]: from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model                                                                                                       

In [8]: User = get_user_model()                                                                                                                              

In [9]: user = User.objects.get(id=8)   

In [10]: permission = Permission.objects.get(name='can run batch actions')                                                                                    
                                                                                                                   
In [11]: user.user_permissions.add(permission)                                                                                                               

In [12]:    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission 
    ...:    from django.contrib.auth.models import User                                                                                                      

In [13]: group_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(group__user=user)                                                                                     

In [14]: group_permissions                                                                                                                                   
Out[14]: <QuerySet [<Permission: slatedoc | slate doc | Can add slate doc>, <Permission: slatedoc | slate doc | can run batch actions>, <Permission: slatedoc | slate doc | Can change slate doc>, <Permission: slatedoc | slate doc | Can delete slate doc>, <Permission: slatedoc | slate doc | Can view slate doc>]>

In [15]: permissions = Permission.objects.filter(user=user)                                                                                                  

In [16]: permissions                                                                                                                                         
Out[16]: <QuerySet [<Permission: sites | site | Can view site>, <Permission: slatedoc | slate doc | Can add slate doc>, <Permission: slatedoc | slate doc | can run batch actions>]>
```

In the view below I have tried to
restrict based on permissions by using either the `test_func` or the `dispatch` methods (dispatch commented out in this example). But in both cases, even though the user has the correct permissions or is in the correct group, the request returns the `Permission Denied` message.

the `test_func` method returns the View that I expect, but for some reason, the `Permission Denied` message is at the top of the page.

the `dispatch` method does not return the view, it redirects back the referring page and the `Permission Denied` message is also the top of the page. I would expect this response if the user did *not* have the correct permissions.

So it seems like I am getting closer to what I expect with the `test_func` method, but I don't understand why the `Permission Denied` message is still in the response?

```
class DocCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, 
                    SuccessMessageMixin, 
                    UserPassesTestMixin, 
                    CreateView):

    model = SlateDoc
    user = get_user_model()
    form_class = SlateDocForm
    template_name = "slatedoc/slatedoc_form.html"
    context_object_name = 'slate'
    success_message = 'Slate successfully created!'
    error_message = "Error saving the Slate, check fields below."

    permission_required = ('slatedoc.add_slatedoc')
    permission_denied_message = "Permission Denied"


    def test_func(self):
        group_permissions = Permission.objects.filter(group__user=self.request.user)

        if not self.request.user.has_perm(permission_required):
            messages.error(self.request, self.permission_denied_message)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
        else:
            handler = getattr(self, self.request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
            return handler(self.request)
        
    # def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):      
    #     if not request.user.has_perm(permission_required):
    #         messages.error(self.request, self.permission_denied_message)
    #         return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    #     else:
    #         handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
    #         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('slatedoc-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, self.error_message)
        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

[image: Permission Denied Banner Message]

Answer (score 0):

this is how i eventually answered my question - much less complicated than I had originally thought.

```
class DocCreateView(
                    PermissionRequiredMixin, 
                    SuccessMessageMixin, 
                    TemplateView
                    ):

        template_name = "slatedoc/slatedoc_create.html"
        permission_required = "slatedoc.add_slatedoc"


    def get_permission_denied_url(self):
        return reverse("slatedoc-index")
```